# Detect two circles with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect that this "pancake" is defective by detecting the circle in it, that is a hole produced during its fabrication.

So far I have managed to detect the big circle that is the hole pancake, but i can not detect the small one.

If someone has an idea on why I am not detecting it, it would be of so much help. This is the code that I am using:

```
    // OpenCV.cpp : Este archivo contiene la función "main". La ejecución del programa comienza y termina ahí.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int history = 1;
float varThreshold = 16;
bool bShadowDetection = true;

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::clock_t start;
    double duracion;
    Mat buena = imread("C:/Users/Jorge/Downloads/ImagenesTortas/TortasUnitarias/Tortasbuenas/B1.bmp");
    Mat mala = imread("C:/Users/Jorge/Downloads/ImagenesTortas/TortasUnitarias/Tortasmalas/Agujereadas/A1.bmp");
    //Mat mala = imread("C:/Users/Jorge/Downloads/ImagenesTortas/TortasUnitarias/Tortasbuenas/B3.bmp");

    if (buena.empty() || mala.empty()) {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int offset_x = 70;
    int offset_y = 70;

    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = offset_x;
    roi.y = offset_y;
    roi.width = buena.size().width - (offset_x * 2);
    roi.height = buena.size().height - (offset_y * 2);

    /* Crop the original image to the defined ROI */

    buena = buena(roi);
    mala = mala(roi);

    start = std::clock();

    cvtColor(buena, buena, CV_BGR2HSV);
    cvtColor(mala, mala, CV_BGR2HSV);

    int tortaBuena = 0;
    int tortaMala = 0;
    int salto = 100;

    cvtColor(mala, mala, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    //medianBlur(mala, mala, 3);
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(mala, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
        buena.rows / 1,  // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
        100, 30, 1, 150 // change the last two parameters
   // (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles
    );
    std::cout << circles.at(0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
    {
        Vec3i c = circles[i];
        Point center = Point(c[0], c[1]);
        // circle center
        circle(mala, center, 1, Scalar(0, 100, 100), 3,8);
        // circle outline
        int radius = c[2];
        circle(mala, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3, 8);
    }

    duracion = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Tiempo: " << duracion << '\n';


    //mostrar las imágenes
    namedWindow("Buena", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Buena", buena);
    namedWindow("Mala", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Mala", mala);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("Buena");
    destroyWindow("Mala");
}
```

And the image:

[image]

Comment: If you started at top-centre of the image and flood-filled the teal/green-blue colour with black, then checked for any teal/green-blue pixels remaining, they would be a hole in the biscuit, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What if the hole is not circular but more of a tear?

I would suggest selecting (or excluding) the background color [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/). Perform a threshold on the result to create a binary image. Next use findContours to detect the pancake and holes.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this image processing pipeline: Convert Image to gray --> Invert the image --> Equalise the image --> Convolve the image with a high pass filter --> Run sobelx and sobely on the image --> threshold the image. If you still have some noise you can you morphology to eliminate them. Im sharing the images on each stage. Once you have a distinct image you can run fincontours() functions on it.

[image: Gray Scale]
[image: Invert]
[image: Equalise]
[image: High Pass]
[image: Sobel]
[image: Threshold]